# After Increase SKU Size to 255 Saleable Qunatity does not displayed anywhere?

Tags: magento2.4.3, sku-length

I Have Increased Sku character length to 255 in database as well in validation But After Increase in size when sku character length increase to 160 the salesable qunatity is not displayed including product admin grid how can i fix this issue.